# how to use proxy server

Tags: internet, proxy

i wanna know to to setup proxy server in ubuntu 12.04 only to access Internet . in  windows i use freegate  to access Internet since all Internet sites are blocked by fortiguard web filtering  . is their is app or setting to bypass web filtering

Answer (score 1):

Yo can use Squid

> Squid is a full-featured web proxy cache server application which
>   provides proxy and cache services for Hyper Text Transport Protocol
>   (HTTP), File Transfer Protocol (FTP), and other popular network
>   protocols. Squid can implement caching and proxying of Secure Sockets
>   Layer (SSL) requests and caching of Domain Name Server (DNS) lookups,
>   and perform transparent caching. Squid also supports a wide variety of
>   caching protocols, such as Internet Cache Protocol, (ICP) the Hyper
>   Text Caching Protocol, (HTCP) the Cache Array Routing Protocol (CARP),
>   and the Web Cache Coordination Protocol. (WCCP)
>
> The Squid proxy cache server is an excellent solution to a variety of
>   proxy and caching server needs, and scales from the branch office to
>   enterprise level networks while providing extensive, granular access
>   control mechanisms and monitoring of critical parameters via the
>   Simple Network Management Protocol (SNMP). When selecting a computer
>   system for use as a dedicated Squid proxy, or caching servers, ensure
>   your system is configured with a large amount of physical memory, as
>   Squid maintains an in-memory cache for increased performance.<sup>1</sup>

To install Squid,  Just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command below:

```
sudo apt-get install squid
```

For complete instructions and configuration take a look at [Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/8.04/serverguide/squid.html)

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Ubuntu Documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/8.04/serverguide/squid.html)</sup>

Comment: I dont think squid will help @shivam. He needs app like freegate to bypass filtering

Answer (score 1):

If you need to bypass web filter you can

1. Access internet via proxy

   Search for proxy (eg: hidemyass.com) and get a proxy address and port and enter them in 
   `Network > Network Proxy >  Method Manual` and Enter IP and PORT
2. Use application like ultrasurf,tor

   take a look at the links: 
   http://abhijaypatne.wordpress.com/2012/02/26/httppackages-debian-orgsearchkeywordswine/
   http://www.torproject.org/docs/debian

Comment: i have tried tor also , it opens the websites but does not unblock other services of the system

Comment: your web filter will be pretty good. what other services?