# proxy chain application

Tags: 12.04, proxy

Please recommend proxy chain application for Ubuntu like proxifier.
Proxifier support proxies in HTTPS and SOCKS. I want an application like proxifier for UBUNTU.

Comment: Take a look at my [answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/276357/how-to-use-proxy-server/276365#276365)

Answer (score 0):

Try proxychain , very similar tool

https://superuser.com/questions/424045/a-software-like-proxifier-for-linux

Other options are to tunnel over ssh

Comment: I think that proxychain doesn't support HTTPS proxies! yes?

Comment: You might want to update your question. If you simply want a proxy, you can use anything from ssh to privoxy to squid to tor. Not sure what you want (punch holes in firewalls or proxy).